# MVC 5 EF 6.1.3 System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using SQL Server. The table I am getting the list from is empty. Using repositories and services.
In my controller:

```
var temp = _courseSvc.ListCourses();
```

Repository:

```
public IQueryable<Course> ListCourses()
{
    return _dbContext.Courses;
}
```

Service:

```
public IQueryable<Course> ListCourses()
{
    return _courseRepository.ListCourses();
}
```

I get this error in the controller when using `var temp = _courseSvc.ListCourses();`

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

However if add this to controller:

```
public IQueryable<Course> ListCourses()
{
    return db.Courses;
}
```

And call it from the `ActionResult`

```
var x = ListCourses();
```

I don't get the error.  All was working before upgrading EF from 5 to 6!
I understand this error happens if table key is null, what I don't understand is why it works directly form the controller and does not from the service!

Stack Trace

> at WebUI.Controllers.CourseController.Index(String searchKW, Boolean searchAsSingleKW) in H:\D_learning\Website 2015\Websitel -Sep_4\HNCLPortal\WebUI\Controllers\CourseController.cs:line 153
>          at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2

Comment: What line is throwing the exception? Are you sure the DbContext instance is not being disposed before the database call?

Comment: show the stack trace

Comment: Can it be that `_courseSvc` is null? The stack trace does not even get to EF...

Comment: will try to call other function from the service to check Ninject.

Comment: Pawel, you are right other calls to the service are not working too!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `_courseSvc` is null. The stack trace shows that you don't even get to call EF.